# Notation for Continuity of solutions with respect to different partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity

Perhaps a naive notation question. Let us say we have some PDE/function defined on $u(x, t)$ where $x \in [0, 1]$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$ (positive reals). Assume the function is continuous with respect to the second derivative of $x$ and only continuous with the respect to the first derivative of $t$. So we can say $u(x, t) \in C^1([0, 1] \times \mathbb{R}^+)$ conservatively, but really, I would like to specify the continuity of the 2nd derivative in the spatial coefficient. One way to do this is to say for fixed $t$, $u(x, t) \in C^2[0, 1]$, but is there a better way?

Comment: Sometimes people write $u \in C^1_t C^2_x ([0,1] \times \mathbb{R}^+)$